# Why twitter cursor is null?

Tags: rest, python-3.x, twitter, cursor, twitter-rest-api

I have some `tweet id`. I want to get `retweeters` of this `tweet`. Therefore, I use this api: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweeters/ids.

There is a example of code written with help `python 3` and [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI):

```
credentials = "credentials.txt"
o = TwitterOAuth.read_file(credentials)
api = TwitterAPI(o.consumer_key, o.consumer_secret, auth_type='oAuth2')

data = api.request('statuses/retweeters/ids', {'id': "370134917713494016", 'count': 100})
```

My result is:

```
{"ids":[id1,id2,..id100],"next_cursor":0,"next_cursor_str":"0","previous_cursor":0,"previous_cursor_str":"0"}
```

I don't understand, why my cursors are null.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, thank you for correcting my stupid errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how [the API for retweeters](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweeters/ids) works.

> While this method supports the cursor parameter, the entire result set can be returned in a single cursored collection. Using the count parameter with this method will not provide segmented cursors for use with this parameter.

You can only get a maximum of 100 users out of it.  So there's no need for a cursor.

Comment: so, why twitter returns zero cursor?

Comment: Cursors are used to move between pages of results. You have all the results. Therefore, the cursor is 0.  There are no more results.

Comment: I am sorry, but why you give me `GET statuses/retweets/:id`? My question is about `GET statuses/retweeters/ids`.

Comment: Sorry @Denis, I've updated my answer with the correct link & text.  The answer is still the same though - you can only get a maximum of 100 IDs out of the API.

Comment: it is okey. But this limit is doing me sad.

Comment: @TerenceEden But shouldn't there be more pages with max 100 each? The documentation says "Causes the list of IDs to be broken into pages of no more than 100 IDs at a time."

Comment: @vloryan this answer is 3 years old - the API may have changed in that time. Please open a new question.